# Issue in sending large JSON data to action method through ajax post in asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am generating an XML using JavaScript and trying to send it to an action method through AJAX POST call. It's working fine up to certain XML length. But as the XML is getting lengthier, I am receiving broken XML in the action method.

I tried followings to increase the request length but still unable to fix the issue. However AJAX GET is working fine.

Please do help me on this.

```
    <configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration> 


<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>


<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have increased **maxJsonLength** but that is for GET only, try to increase the value of **maxRequestLength** also..